# Node.js njwt Signature verification failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

Im building a application where i want to use jwt-tokens for authentication. i followed the tutorial on this website: https://stormpath.com/blog/nodejs-jwt-create-verify

The problem is when i want to use the verify function i get this error: 
 JwtParseError: Signature verification failed.

And i cant figure out what im doing wrong.

The moment i create the token i save it in my database along with the secret key. Then i sent this token to the browser. The browser sents this token back, at that moment i search for the token in my database. Then i use the token and the secretkey that was stored with it to verify. At that moment i get the error.

Code when i build token and store it:

```
                        let secretkey = Jwt.createKey();
                        let token = Jwt.getToken(message.id, message.adress, 0);
                        const mySql = new mysql();
                        mySql.insertToken(message.id, token, secretkey);
```

Code when i get token and verify:

```
        mySql.getFromDB(token,(err, result)=>{
        let body = result[0];
        const Jwt = new jwt();
        let secretkey = Buffer.from(body.secretkey, 'base64');
        let jwtcheck = Jwt.checkJWT(body.token, secretkey);
        //console.log(jwtcheck);
```

The other strange thing is that when i run the jwt.io debugger. I enter my token and it says verification failed, but when I click on the "secret base64 encoded" button, it says signature verified.

Pls can someone help me?

Thanks

update*

code for jwt.getToken:

```
    createKey()
{
    this.secretkey = uuid();
    return secretkey;
}


createClaims(ssub, iiss, ppermissions)
{
    let claims = {
        sub: ssub,
        iss: iiss,
        permissions: ppermissions
    };
    return claims;
}



createJWT(secretkey, sub, iss, permissions)
{
    const jwt = nJwt.create(this.createClaims(sub, iss, permissions), secretkey);
    return jwt;
}


getToken(sub, iss, permissions)
{

    const jwt = this.createJWT(this.secretkey, sub, iss, permissions);
    const token = jwt.compact();
    return token;
}
```

Comment: `.createKey` and `.getToken` are not API methods on the default export in the njwt library entry. Are you using njwt or some other jwt node library?

Comment: No their my own functions, the creatkey() make a key using the uuid library and the getToken functions uses the nJwt.create function

Comment: can you edit your question with the implementation for `Jwt.getToken`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Soo i figured it out. The moment i create my secret. i had to encode it to a base64, so the method would look like this:

```
createKey()
{
    this.secretkey = uuid();
    console.log(secretkey);
    this.secretkeybase = Buffer.from(secretkey).toString('base64');
    return this.secretkeybase;
}
```

At this moment the token gets verified.

Answer (score 0):

I belive that you must explicity define a **secret key**, like `Jwt.createKey("you-secretkey-here");` and use the same key in `Jwt.checkJWT(body.token, "you-secretkey-here");`. Try to pass the same **secret key** from the `Jwt.createKey` to `Jwt.checkJWT` function.

Comment: i looked it up, and the secret key i stored in the database is exactly the same like the secretkey i used when i made the token, the part that confuses me is when i use the token in the jwt.io debugger and click the button for "secret base64 encoded"  it says signature verified, might be a problem with the secretkey and base64?

Comment: Yeah it seems to be a problem with the base64, did you tried without base64?

Comment: Well i get the token in the header of an REST API GET from the browser to the server. I tried to decode  it or encode it, but nothing helps

Comment: Are you using **expressjs** with Nodejs?